# What is the difference between attachMatched() and attachPatternMatched() and/or attachRouteMatched() and attachRoutePatternMatched() in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

Would be happy about an example of what is the difference between the following SAPUI5 routing approaches:

**`sap.ui.core.routing.Route`**:

- `attachMatched()`
- `attachPatternMatched()`

**`sap.ui.core.routing.Router`**:

- `attachRouteMatched()`
- `attachRoutePatternMatched()`

API says for `attachMatched()` and `attachPatternMatched()` nothing about any difference.

API says for `attachRouteMatched()`:

> Attach event-handler `fnFunction` to the `routeMatched` event of this
>   `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`.

API says for `attachRoutePatternMatched()`:

> Attach event-handler `fnFunction` to the `routePatternMatched` event of
>   this `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`. This event is similar to route
>   matched. But it will only fire for the route that has a matching
>   pattern, not for its parent `Routes`.

E.g. could use

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.Detail", {
        onInit: function () {
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);              
            // oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
        },
        _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").invoicePath,
                model: "invoice"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

or

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.Detail", {
        onInit: function () {
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
            // oRouter.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
        },
        _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").invoicePath,
                model: "invoice"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

No difference to see. Don't get «But it will only fire for the route that has a matching pattern, not for its parent Routes.» Thought `attachRouteMatch()` would fire only as well for the route that has a matching pattern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differences in this context are:

1. `sap.ui.core.routing.Route` and `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`

`sap.ui.core.routing.Route`'s `attachMatched` or `attachPatternMatched` fires for a specific stated route. In the following the route «detail»:

```js
let oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
```

---

`sap.ui.core.routing.Router`'s `attachRouteMatched` or `attachRoutePatternMatched` fires for any route:

```js
let oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);            
oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
```

For the sake of clarification: the `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`'s methods would have the same results as `sap.ui.core.routing.Route`'s if a restriction was added for a specific route:

```js
_onObjectMatched: function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") !== "detail") {
        …
    }
}
```

But nevertheless, `sap.ui.core.routing.Router` fires `_onObjectMatched` for any route. The restriction to the detail route occurs in the fired method `_onObjectMatched` with the if clause. `sap.ui.core.routing.Route` fires `_onObjectMatched` in the first place only if the «detail» route is hit.

2. `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`'s `attachMatched`/`sap.ui.core.routing.Route`'s `attachRouteMatched` and `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`'s `attachPatternMatched`/`sap.ui.core.routing.Route`'s `attachRoutePatternMatched`

`attachMatched`/`attachRouteMatched` fires for a matched **route**. `attachMatched` fires for any route **or subroute**. `attachRouteMatched` fires for a specified route's match.

---

**To conclude:**

- `attachPatternMatched`/`attachRoutePatternMatched` fires for a matched **subroute**.
- `attachPatternMatched` fires for the route's **subroutes**.
- `attachRoutePatternMatched` fires for any matched subroute. i.e. `attachPatternMatched`/`attachRoutePatternMatched` fires for no parent routes.

---

**tl;dr:**

- Specific route with `sap.ui.core.routing.Route`.
- No specific route with `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`.
- `attachMatched`/`attachRouteMatched` fires for any route.
- `attachPatternMatched`/`attachRoutePatternMatched` fires for subroutes or, not for parent routes.